# Color country polygon in amcharts5

Tags: maps, amcharts5

does anyone know how to color any one specific country (say for eg France) after onload on amcharts5? On v4 you could do:

```
polygonSeries.getPolygonById("France").isActive = true;
activeState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#24dd32");
```

however `getPolygonById` isnt working in v5. Neither is am4core.color("#24dd32");. Among many other ways i tried doing:

```
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.set({
  id: "France",  // or id:"FR",
  fill: am5.color("#66ff66"),
  fillOpacity: 1
});
```

but this doesnt work.

Thanks